# Rank system, with alert

Tags: php, cakephp, php-arc

im trying to build a rank system, were you have a user with an x amount of miles runed, and all his friend has their x amount of miles,

now my architectural problem is, how can I make it so that i will have an array of the friends ordered by miles desc, and i need to know if my user has passed any of the friends.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: to tell you the truth, I'm still thinking, on thebest way to do this, i need more friends with brains, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the array using `arsort`. Example:

```
$arr = array('2', '356', '8', '103.4');
arsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

It'll sort the array to something like this:

```
$arr = array('356', '103.4', '8', '2');
```

Then, to your other question, *How do I know if user has passed any of the friends*.

```
if(count(array_intersect($milesCount, $arr)) > 0) {
   echo 'User has passed at least one element in friends list.';
}
```